# Sum a calculated <td> value

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a calculator that converts a different opioids medications to a standard opioid dosage. The calculator converts all medications fine but I cannot get the javaScript sum() function to add it all up when a button is clicked. Please help.

Of note, the "totalMED += total[i]).value;" code inside the for loop breaks the medication calculate function (no value is displayed). I don't know why.

P.S. I realize both calculate() functions are basically the same but I couldn't get the relevant  values to loop through a single function. I seem to have problems with loops.

```
Updated code with comments:
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="date.js"></SCRIPT>
   <style type="text/css">
   ...
   </style>
   </head>
    <body> 
     <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Medications</th>
          <th>Daily Dose (mg)</th>
          <th>MED</th>
          <th>Medications</th>
          <th>Daily Dose (mg)</th>
          <th>MED</th> 
        </tr>    
         <tr>
          // ---this input box is really just a label----
          <td><input class="tg-yw41" type=”text” name=”Tramadol” value=Tramadol id="med” 
                disabled></td>

           //    ----This input box takes user entered dosage, calls calculate() function, and 
           //       passes the conversion factor---
          <td>'TEXT"</td><td><input class ="tg-yw41" type=”text” name=”dose” value="" 
                placeholder="0" Id="r18c2" onchange="calculate28('.1')"></td>

        //---This input box receives the value from the calculate function via Id="MED- 
        //     Tramadol". Also includes name="sum" for sum() function.
          <td><input Id="MED-Tramadol" type=”text” name="sum" value="" disabled></td>

        //----The next three rows are just duplicate of above
          <td><input class="tg-yw41" type=”text” name=”Sufentanil” value="Sufentanil" 
                disabled></td>
          <td><input class ="tg-yw41" type=”text” name=”dose” value="" placeholder="0" 
               Id="r18c5" onchange="calculate29('60')"></td>
          <td><input Id="MED-Sufentanil-intra" type=”text” name="sum" value="" disabled></td> 
      </tr>
       <tr>
          //-----Label
          <td><input  value="Total Daily Morphine Equivalent Dose (MED) in Milligrams" 
               disabled></td>

          //---Input box that should receive value from sum() function (via ID="r19c2")
          <td><input class ="tg-yw41" type=”text” name=”dose” value="" placeholder="0" 
              Id="r19c2"></td>
       </tr>

        //A button that when clicked calls the sum() function
   </table>
     <button type="button" onclick="sum()">MED total</button>
```

JavaScript functions

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   //Takes user input * passed conversion factor, assigns value to 
     document.getElementById('MED-Tramadol')
   function calculate28(x) 
  {
    var my1 = x;
    var my2 = document.getElementById('r18c2').value;
    //Note: value is parsed as a Float...don't know if it gets converted back to string
    document.getElementById('MED-Tramadol').value = parseFloat(my1) * parseFloat(my2);        
   }

  //same as above
  function calculate29(x) 
   {
    var my1 = x;
    var my2 = document.getElementById('r18c5').value;
    document.getElementById('MED-Sufentanil-intra').value = parseFloat(my1) * parseFloat(my2);        
   }

    //Supposed to combine all values from calculate() function assigned to respective boxes
    function sum() {
    //should collect value from all <input> with name="sum"
      var total = document.getElementsByName('sum').value; 
      var sum = 0;
       for(var i=0; i<total.length; i++)
      {

        totalMED += paredFloat(total[i]).value); 

       }
      document.getElementById('r19c2').value = totalMED;
```

Comment: This is totally invalid code `totalMED += total[i]).value; `, the right parenthesis is missing the left one.

Comment: That must have been a copy error. The original has the left parentheses. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: That set of parentheses may be part of the problem. Would it be possible for you to update your question so that the code no longer has a copy error?

Comment: updated code with commetns

Answer (score 1):

When you pull the value of an input box, it's read as a string. Use `parseInt()` to get the number, otherwise you're concatenating strings.

Since you're taking in user input, you should also validate it. A simple way to make sure you don't get NaN is to pull the value into a temporary variable and test it before parsing.

```
var strTemp = total[i].value;

if (strTemp)
{
    totalMED += parseInt(test);
}
```

EDIT: I ignored the paren, thinking it was just a typo in the question. I decided I shouldn't. You'll see small errors like the unmatched `)` inside your call easily if you check your browser's JS console, as this would certainly halt the program and provide an error message.

Comment: parsing to an int is not an issue because the code was already parsed in the calculate function() and the sum() pulls from that calculated value. I added updated code above with parseFloat (did not help) and added some comments for clarity. Also, I never had a NaN output, there was no output at all.

Comment: I'd look at M12 Bennett's answer again then. The operations performed are being printed to the browser console (reading your other comments, I'm not sure you're using it). While it isn't fixing your code specifically, it is a demonstration of correctly using `getElementsByName()` - i.e. you're calling `value` on an array which won't work. Remove that bit, and assuming you're parsing everything that needs it, then the loop will work.

Comment: Thank you for the info on value not calling with arrays. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to post this answer out here, and if it doesn't help or it's close then we can edit as we see fit.

First of all, are you sure that you are receiving the correct values in each of the variables?  For example, `var total = document.getElementsByName('sum').value;` should return as `undefined`.

Secondly, `totalMED += total[i]).value;` is not valid Javascript, and even if `var total = document.getElementsByName('sum').value;` were to give you an array of actual values.. then `totalMED += total[i]).value;` would just concatenate strings.  For example, if you have 2 `input` elements on your page, and the first has a value of `20` and the second has a value of `25` then, your output would be `02025`, because `value` is of type `string`.

I think this may help:

**Javascript**

```
function sum() 
{
    var total = document.getElementsByName('sum');
    var totalMED = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < total.length; i++)
    {
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(total[i].value)))
      {
          console.log(total[i].value);
          totalMED += parseInt(total[i].value);
      }

    }

    console.log(totalMED);
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLe4j7on/48/) to prove that it's working.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I had previously used parseFloat(totalMED += total[i]).value; but removed it since the value being passed from the calculate() function was passed as a Float, and I am just taking that same value. I am not looping the user input, I am looping a calculated value that was already parsed. I will play with it and get back to you.

Comment: So, the values that should be in the `name` elements are **definitely** floats or ints?  Is that what you expect?  If so, then there is no need to parse the numbers again in the `sum` function

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Your code in JSFiddle has values already set in the input boxes. In my code they are calculated and added after user input from a different <input>. Does not work. parseFloat was also not the issue. I have added updated code above with comments for clarity.

Comment: @Marty I understand that my code does not **exactly** match yours, but it shouldn't matter if I have predefined values for my inputs or if I'm getting them from another user input.. the main point is that I fixed your `sum` method to work as expected.

Comment: @Marty I've updated my fiddle to look **very close** to the code you posted.  I have it working.  Let me know.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work. I really wanted it to. I have 400 lines of code and I am starting to wonder if the functions are conflicting with each other. I think I may rearrange functions using if statements. FWIW, the code "totalMED += total[i]).value;" breaks the app so the dosages won't convert anymore. Something has to be going on there. I also need to look more into the Console.Log. Thank you for your help.  If I get it figured out I will come back and add a comment, just as an FYI.

Comment: @Marty only you can tell us if functions are conflicting with each other.. I highly doubt that they are since you are explicitly telling the element to use a specific function with the `onchange` event.. as for the `totalMED += total[i]).value;`.. that is breaking due to the `)` character.. that is not valid Javascript.

Comment: I typed the wrong syntax here, I had everything correct in my source code. I  was typing fast and thought you would just read the line of code in general versus the specific syntax. I didn't really expect you to look into it. I am pretty new here (second question). I will be more careful.

Comment: Just as a FYI, I finally figured it out. For whatever reason I had to add a class "sum" and use document.querySelectorAll('.sum') instead of document.getElementByName('sum') to create the node list. Thanks again for your help.